# Box Muller Transform is leaning to the right

Tags: netlogo, distribution, gaussian, normal-distribution, probability-distribution

I am building a computational simulation (Netlogo) of the spread of disinformation.
For a start, I want to distribute the political preference of the population following a basic Gaussian distribution (later on I can adjust the distribution to my liking).
I know that the Box Muller Transform is the easiest way to do this.
However, when implementing it, I find that the plot  [always has a tendency to lean to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtud8.png).
Does someone know why this is and how I can prevent it?
Also, [y2 gives a very different plot than y1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsom1.png). When looking it examples of Box Muller, they all show two plots with similar Gaussian distribution. Does someone also know the reason for this doesn't happen with my code?
I used the following code:

```
let u1 random-float 1
let u2 random-float 1
let z1 sqrt (-2 * ln u1) * cos (2 * pi * u2)
let z2 sqrt (-2 * ln u1) * sin (2 * pi * u2)
report z1
```

random-float 1 means it will pick a floating point number between 0 and 1.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

NetLogo uses degrees for angles and I think that form is for radians. But this is all unnecessarily complicated if all you want to do is draw from a normal distribution, there is a `random-normal` function